# Google mail push notifications in WP8.1 - is it supported again?

Tags: sync, calendars, gmail, google, push-notifications

It's fairly well known that WP lost the ability to receive push notifications (check for new email as it arrives) after Google made changes in the last few months.

But I can't find a clear answer if this is supposed to have been fixed in WP8.0 or the upcoming 8.1? My understanding as per [this page](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-gdr2-google-account-support) is that the problem was Google disabling support for Microsoft's Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) technology in favour of more open technologies like IMAP, CalDAV, etc.

However in my brand new 1020 running WP8.0, I still don't see an option to receive notifications as emails arrive on any of my google accounts (I have gmail and business google accounts). The linked article suggests this was fixed in GDR2 which I thought we already had in 8.0.

What is the current state of play with WP8.0 and 8.1?

Comment: On my Lumia 920 running 8.1 dev preview, I can set "Download new email" to  "as items arrive" for my Google account. But what's stopping you from upgrading your 1020 to 8.1 and finding out for yourself?

Comment: There's no way I'm updating to 8.1 until it makes general release! If you have it in 8.1 but didn't in 8.0, I think this is a legitimate answer to the question though...

Comment: Fair enough. Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8.1 Preview for Developers, the option to sync Gmail emails "as items arrive" is definitely available:

[image]

When I enabled that option (normally it's set to manual sync as I don't really use Gmail) and sent myself a couple of test emails, they showed up almost immediately in the notification centre as well as on the live tile. So it's working just fine.

I don't have access to any phones running WP 8.0 so I can't say if that option should be available and working, sorry.

Comment: Don't know if this apply to everybody. When Google cut this support year ago it said people already using it will continue to be allowed. Don't know if it will work for a person syncing the first time his Google Account in Windows Phone. Mine has this option two.

Comment: This option was added in 8.1. Prior to updating my phone I was on 8.0 GDR3 and didnt have it.

Comment: Also, Google's commitment was per account, per phone. Same on different hardware, or after a reset didn't work - until 8.1